# Is there any keyboard shortcut for entering El Capitan’s split view?

Tags: keyboard, macos

El Capitan’s new [split view](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-split-view-in-os-x-el-capitan/) is an interesting feature. At last, OS X users have a feature at their disposal that has long been available on various Linuxes or on Windows. However, I have not yet found any way to enter it with the keyboard alone, without any mouse or trackpad interaction.

Yes, I am a keyboard junky and I think the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> keyboard shortcuts that are available on Windows or on many Linuxes are very handy. I would appreciate anything similar – a setting, a menu entry, or even an extra app or script.

The [BetterTouchTool](http://boastr.net/) allows for setting keyboad shortcuts for *Maximize Window Left* and *Maximize Window Right*. However, that is not quite the same, since it does not make use of the proper split view.

So, is there a way to enter the split view with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BetterTouchTool (starting with version 1.22, currently available as alpha version) let's you assign gestures or keyboard shortcuts to trigger the native split screen.

Comment: Thanks – I have not been able to find that alpha version, though.

Comment: It's currently only available when checking for alpha versions in BetterTouchTool. However the public release will be available sometime this weekend.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any way to achieve this. I've trawled the web in search of an answer.

When I first moved to Mac from Linux, I picked [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) for this kind of window manipulation. It's the best tool I could find that has a full range of keyboard shortcuts. I'll be sticking with it for the foreseeable future. (It costs $12.99 but the free trial version doesn't expire)

Comment: Thanks – SizeUp seems to be a more dedicated app for this than the BetterTouchTool, and it provides a nice visual feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/), which explicitly apes the winkey+arrow behavior from Windows 7/8/10.

Answer (score 1):

I've used BetterTouchTool which has now branched into BetterTouchTool and BetterSnapTool to resize windows using programmable multitouch gestures and keyboard shortcuts.

Link to BetterSnapTool in the app store: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that the BetterSnapTool, a dedicated spin-off of the BetterTouchTool, claims it supports the Split View, see [BetterSnapTool El Capitan Compatibility](http://blog.boastr.net/bettersnaptool-el-capitan-compatibility/).

Unfortunately, I have not been able to test the trial version. It does not open, probably because I had already tested a previous version in the past.

Answer (score 0):

As a long time Windows user, I find Magnet by CrowdCafe, to be a very nice window snapping tool.

It includes keyboard shortcut commands for:

- Left
- Right
- Up (half)
- Down (half)
- 1/4 screen (left top, right top, left bottom, right bottom)
- Max screen
- Multi screen support and others

Can be found in the App Store.

Only thing missing is the auto adjust slider when apps are side by side and you resize them.